# how to insert multiple data with their own type?

Tags: php, mysql

```
<input name="names[]" type="text"/><select><option value="male">male</option><option value="female">female</option></select>  
<input name="names[]" type="text"/><select><option value="male">male</option><option value="female">female</option></select>  
<input name="names[]" type="text"/><select><option value="male">male</option><option value="female">female</option></select>  





    if (!empty($_POST['names'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['names'] AS $names) {
        // add to the database
        if (!empty($names)){
            $rs=mysql_query("SELECT names FROM table WHERE names = '$names' LIMIT 1");
            if(mysql_num_rows($rs) == 0) {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (names,gender) VALUES ('$names','$gender')");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This does inset the names however i don't know how i can make the genders work for each individual name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give your SELECT elements a name:

```
<input name="names[]" type="text"/><select name="genders[]"><option value="male">male</option><option value="female">female</option></select>
```

Now you can use the key of `$_POST['names']` to get the corresponding gender:

```
foreach ($_POST['names'] AS $key => $names) {
    // add to the database
    if (trim($names) != '' && !empty($_POST['genders'][$key]) && in_array($_POST['genders'][$key], array('male', 'female'))) {
        $gender = $_POST['genders'][$key];
        $rs = mysql_query("SELECT names FROM table WHERE names = '".mysql_real_escape_string($names).' LIMIT 1");
        if (mysql_num_rows($rs) == 0) {
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (names,gender) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($names)."','$gender')");
        }
    }
}
```

You should also use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) to sanatize the data sent by the user.